# http response que es este código y cómo lo puedo guardar en formato jpg?

Tags: http, tcp, response

Tengo la siguiente curiosidad. Si realizo una petición a través de **TCP/IP** a un servidor me devuelve un código que no entiendo ni qué es, ni cómo lo puedo guardar.

*Resumiendo mi pregunta:* Quiero guardar la respuesta del servidor en formato *jpg*, pero al meter el código que me envía en un archivo con extensión *jpg* no funciona(he copiado y pegado tal cual ha llegado). La petición la he realizado a través de **netcat**. No busco guardar la imagen con **wget** ni nada, sólo me gustaría comprender qué es ese código raro que me envía el servidor y por qué no lo puedo guardar en un archivo y que funcione.

He realizado la petición a la siguiente imagen:

http://kaboompics.com/files/upload/o_1aqd50lvlpd71hgv10361op4vdk7_new.jpg

Éste es mi request:

```
GET /files/upload/o_1aqd50lvlpd71hgv10361op4vdk7_new.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: kaboompics.com
Accept: */*
```

Y esto es lo que me llega del servidor(response):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Expires: Sun, 05 Feb 2017 10:39:27 GMT
ETag: "51129-57b4d237-7f06ee67a312ca10"
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 21:08:07 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 332073
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 10:39:27 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
```

body response:

```
����JFIF��<CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 100
��C��C��,"��    
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?��l��Ք��up(s�6�$����1����_5<�H��\E�p&L��s�-���k
i�̑�*�B�89m�xq�3���mXK��+�mPNb� �1�����$�lc�M�/U���4����8ͻ0�G�NH!��np8�I����ח�'�&�##�������$
�b�s�,��ݰ��B�������zц��cر����:�F�   ��rWv���F����_�;b�!Fd��d�dr3���
�$��xk� VU�el'$�I �l�0;k*�P�D�����y���7ul3�����,b�I� �BN`�d��嬹����r���������4���gRʬ,�W���a�y� ����|���[sʐE�*�P��3*����$ 
Đ�ڝ��a!�6�����a� ��8rMq�RZ�һ���s��,�O��z���-���FSQo�ۯ��+�v�����>v��##���*dA�
}��{�BDأ
���B��;�o�  ��Q��>�M ��6�x��z�������6ua��|N��墶D(�(�VR�mQ����9�ɵ6ݬ������f��+���� C�6��g�ʳ�v�˓�pNk[יʹ�t_���'.%H' �]���̑ɱB�@
�ʏ���
�9�9TX�ֲ�v7vHPcnܪ�*��[���|�8�P:`���M��n6�Եwz��BI?1��\��N9�8$�Yu�$�#�V�v�@��/�@-������.���;*�bU`W8ݴn��e��@ ��WR�R�P�gH�q��� ��2��� 
�>ﶿ���k����F��E�C"��X���pN0z��%j�����bv��a��+� ���  #�԰� �m]�X�9a���2ų܀@Q��/ c���aE����}�I �ŕ�9C����Q($�W��y�3�W����:   .�y0��  t�������N2�0˾����ɵ�V ��pK�NT��UIukqfUV��s�n*I�\�V-�g��j�/w�c�o��C   ���c����0��J߁R��uwo��\x�+yR��.�Å]�,p�
��U$�&���e�)#C.N    =nr� yn���v�^>��;C��nr�T�?/
I��T$1=��l���
\�n�Ǣ��@\7TU���ߡ��;�cԯ�H���ݜ�و`�6���$oe�*���]�g,CeF�)�w#vYF�z���>Y%�`']ʹ1�H,݉ �o��#����,����!�;�0*U@^�mb��i�;l����̞g}�o#�㼔ͼH=ξc��QA���pޤ�����$��,��GP�R�[;�$���Am�I��B !���?)dm�7d�!��� �HC1gR����>W%�$���MK����A��_��zp�UeU26���y�@8Tp V�ĮjC~d����ew.�p��͂K|��������8P�2   b�ź��]�v����O#�쵈�I�L�m%���̅R�
����8+�ky~cRk���;��H��60�d��ّ���� �������\�I*�9S�8 (�����ԮO���`��:P��(������2!�8l��NH]ʸ\ORB����\/�H�5����
�جľ��c9V,� �p8䘚�c�Am�)' �,�������Y�n%��3Мc���l��s�I`j��znPA�8PXm|�~\��s�3�Vv-j�hI1_�}�!VS��q�%r�X��U�fS��s��2������e����5�Wl��NH<1��A�$�'ni5���y�'*0H'?9bpr@�x c4Y�����W�>R]��  <��q�Ae'>��"��Yv��� R�`r3���9"�K}�3 ��bU��]��g$�n�FH�k0+�aU�,2�%�f\.8\m�T�2M
5�  /�@$���*v+�H�:ڤ�@�L��r�Uf��V.�v���n#8m�p��!rp�c��T�灖;�N�Y�fw��T�����;��� R�\��b���pX(%q��N�z�20A3t�ueu. ,���p@}����2��# QΫr��<�R2pK89
�˒P�KH$@K)S���ew�8*H+���4Y��g��/%��71�B�hP�+��@�韙?0�0Y.�U?:�    -�_�F�d�%��1�`�^lߠ,3��@��,9�    ���߶��v1�[�"���v�A!Nr����nIo�u:�~��r6���@�3��d�
��T���cnI�s�J��$�e',9J_�)R�pp�  $�r���1�9Q�F'R��D!r�'s�9<+(��J�r�y�,��ԓW�θ]�`��T���a�8<�p��#f�h��nU?1�As��,F���prEq1ݙfp�c���X��G`pAi4�������3��!�큲H���B�{!�����[xa?�\��I8 r0HS�B�9I@ܧ9ry<�6���$�N�I�����d�c�`8�FN�� =3���g1H���3�Ӟh'$n��#�[��������>�NN�I �0��Ċ�����ހd��6�RWkg�q�9|�0$�vo�*>a�H��\|���1�� ,o��ml�ey  bH��
F���Z�Y�s�;-�T��6��$�A�U+��6�\d��f#8�
�q��AA�sή��Yv�fffR+�L���T�Mi�(eT��RT�ݥq�>���!r2]�g�f�� �3�1;dÜ���e3����-}v��ڸ����~m��,�+�+Uo��)c�"���v�������#���79�>���9�2O����@\rARWh��c�'
1�K��_�}țkM��_��&���؀0��s'�ӌs��
J�PY����ڣ��A���U?���b�y�X����\����q g�r:�����1�(UrF���C���0y�$i�^���2�Mǝ3��n^�d���z��6I=v���0Pp�a���n$�*��*@�*v�p
b�p�K�����c���<�q��n+�p��� HTd��3�q��
�)ǶA;)[���U�P�N�ۘ��z|�0(?�ӓ��*^B#)A����6ܜa@$arI=FT1�MD���B�u�$2A�+���'md�kbM�x;�.m���=��Oഝ�Ore$ս�Ȯ|���G.��\��B�a��M�F<���*L������ ���0X��0������
�=� ����/!wQ� +�V��8�ۓ��q�mV �r�݀2ē�1���A�n�n���a.]}�~�3gGi
�T�Ai�lwI��gj� �ug\�2��]�z9V��X&��O�8@�)q�H��Z2d+����E�G@�'��p.�ݷ"���%2�P���.��'5�#/�ha)�'w�z�[\.����*T�*��<��,�8ub �V��@������@wVbp������|��6�o���˴����2Jc�e*+:k��M�y�VC��*
```

EDITO:

Llevo varios días con esta duda y no sé si la resolveré finalmente. Con el comentario de Trauma he pasado todo por un editor *hexadecimal*, quedando el resultado como sigue:

```
1º Descarga de la imagen original vía web
2º Realización de un request a la imagen vía la web **requestmaker**
3º Realización de un request a la imagen vía **netcat**
```

De los resultados obtengo lo siguiente:

1º La imagen original(guardada como imagen.jpg) ocupa en disco *332.073 bytes (325 KiB)*. 
El body que me da **requestmaker** es de *86.668 bytes (85 KiB)* y la respuesta que me da netcat a la petición(incluyendo headers y body) es de *331.355 bytes (324 KiB)*, al borrar los headers y dejar sólo el body del archivo no varía mucho el tamaño total.

Como se ve esto ya da que pensar que algo no está bien porque no coinciden ninguno de los tres.

2º Paso los tres por un editor hexadecimal, siendo el resultado que tanto la imagen.jpg como en el request hecho a través de web aparece cierto texto legible, identificando algo el tipo de archivo porque aparece la palabra *JPG* y la palabra *QUALITY=100*. 
En el archivo creado con netcat directamente es todo *hexadecimal* sin conversión legible(todo símbolos).
El único archivo de los tres que se puede abrir como imagen es lógicamente el primero descargado de la web, los otros son inservibles. Además el archivo imagen.jpg es el único que tiene los caracteres *hexadecimales* que corresponden a una imagen *(FF D8 FF E0)*

No se me ocurre que más puedo hacer.

EDICIÓN 2:

Tras seguir con las pruebas un día sin saber el motivo ya me funciona. No he cambiado(conscientemente) nada así que no sé que pudo ser. Al descargar la imagen con netcat baja con el tamaño correcto y el formato correcto. Ahora sí puedo visualizarla

Comment: _"he copiado y pegado tal cual ha llegado"_ No puedes "copiar y pegar" datos binarios.

Comment: Con wget:
``$ wget -O x.jpg http://kaboompics.com/files/upload/o_1aqd50lvlpd71hgv10361op4vdk7_new.jpg
--2017-01-08 09:23:00--  http://kaboompics.com/files/upload/o_1aqd50lvlpd71hgv10361op4vdk7_new.jpg
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 332073 (324K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘x.jpg’

100%[======================================>] 332,073      265KB/s   in 1.2s

2017-01-08 09:23:02 (265 KB/s) - ‘x.jpg’ saved [332073/332073]

``

Cuál es el problema?

Comment: leonbloy eran dos errores, primero, copiaba y pegaba según me llegaba(ahora se que eso está mal). Segundo, algún tipo de problema de sintaxis que no he sabido identificar pues cambié muchísimas veces la forma de lanzar el comando hasta que funcionó. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta del servidor te indica todos los datos que necesitas:

> Content-Type: image/jpeg

Indica que te envia un **archivo** en formato jpeg.

> Content-Length: 332073

Indica la longitud del archivo, en bytes.

> Connection: close

El servidor cerrará la conexión, no esperando nuevas peticiones.

La imagen que indicas, si compruebas su tamaño, verás que es de exactamente **332073 bytes**.

La cabecera no indica ningún otro dato relevante, como pudiera ser la compresión utilizada.

El servidor te está mandando justamente lo que tu esperas, una imagen. Bastaría con hacer lo que indicas, guardar el `BODY` y renombrarlo. Tu esquema es correcto.

No tengo experiencia con `netcat`, así que no puedo indicarte como hacerlo. Recuerda no abrir el archivo con un editor de texto, sino con algún editor que admita datos binarias. Y que la cabecera va separada de los datos por **2** saltos de línea.

**EDITO**

El sitio [RequestMaker][1] **no está pensado** para respuestas binarias; el cuadro de texto en el que muestra el resultado se llena de caracteres `?`, lo cual suele indicar que están ocurriendo errores o problemas con la codificación del texto; esto es consecuencia de los datos binarios; el sitio intenta interpretarlos como texto, con cierta codificación (seguramente espera UTF-8).

La codificación UTF-8 tiene ciertas reglas, que **no se cumplen** en datos binarios. Ciertos *bytes* tienen valores especiales, y **no todas las combinaciones de** *bytes* **están permitidas**. Esos errores son representados por ese caracter `?`. Y faltarán datos; esas secuencias de *mas de 1 byte* mostradas como *un solo byte `?`* implica que el resultado ofrecido por la página es *mas pequeño* que el resultado real.

**EDITO 2**

Tras instalar el `netcat`, y siguiendo exactamente tus pasos

```
netcat kaboompics.com 80 > prueba.dat
```

> GET /files/upload/o_1aqd50lvlpd71hgv10361op4vdk7_new.jpg HTTP/1.1
>   Host: kaboompics.com
>   Accept: * / *

Obtengo un archivo de 332406 bytes. Si listamos sus primeras 13 líneas:

```
head -n 13 prueba.dat
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
>   Expires: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 11:48:38 GMT
>   ETag: "51129-57b4d237-7f06ee67a312ca10"
>   Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 21:08:07 GMT
>   Content-Type: image/jpeg
>   Content-Length: 332073
>   Date: Sun, 08 Jan 2017 11:48:38 GMT
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Server: LiteSpeed
>   Connection: close
>   
>   ?????JFIF??CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 100

Se aprecia que el archivo gráfico, los datos descargados, comienzan justamente en la lína 13 (la línea 12 está en blanco, pero es relevante).

Este número, las 12 líneas, variará de un servidor a otro (e incluso puede que de una petición a otra). Recordemos que las cabeceras se separan de los datos mediante **una línea en blanco** que **estará siempre presente**.

Ahora, si descartamos esas primeras 12 líneas

```
tail -n +13 prueba.dat > image.jpg
```

Obtenemos el resultado final, un archivo de 332073 *bytes*.

**EDITO 3**

Podemos encontrar los finales de línea tanto así `\n` como `\r\n`, dependiendo del servidor. Esto nos puede ocasionar algún *problemilla* para automatizar el proceso de eliminar los *headers* del *body*.

Este comando

```
sed '1,/^\r\{0,1\}$/d' prueba.dat > image.jpg
```

Tiene en cuenta esto, y nos elimina todas las cabeceras; elimina líneas, hasta que encuentre una en blanco, independientemente de como estén codificados los finales de línea.

Comment: Pues algo estoy haciendo mal, lo estaba guardando con sublimetext.
Desde la pagina requestmaker también se puede hacer la petición y copiar el body, no hace falta que sea netcat. Voy a buscar info sobre eso de un editor de datos binarios a ver si tengo suerte.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo en RequestMaker (no lo conocia). Ese sitio está preparado para *respuestas de texto*, tales como páginas HTML. **NO** lo puedes hacer copiando y pegando desde ahí.

Comment: Gracias Trauma por las molestias. Por tu ayuda he aprendido más sobre el manejo de linux porque me diste una línea y fui investigando.
Finalmente no sé qué falló, lancé el comando muchísimas veces y lo cambié varias veces por si acaso. Puede que alguna línea con mala sintaxis, un salto de línea, etc, pero al final lo conseguí. Ahora a seguir aprendiendo cositas nuevas. Gracias mil!